# Bluemix CLI dev plugin not available

Tags: ibm-cloud, command-line-interface

Trying to install bluemix CLI plugin for dev , but it keeps failing on mac

```
bluemix plugin install dev -r Bluemix
```

the error seen is

```
FAILED. Unable to download the plug-in binary from the URL https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net/downloads/bluemix-plugins/dev/dev-darwin-amd64-0.1.5.
```

Looks like the latest plugin(from catalog) has not been updated in the download location, as going to http://public.dhe.ibm.com/cloud/bluemix/cli/bluemix-plugins/dev/ shows the version available as [only previous plugin version available - 0.0.6 not 0.1.5 which came from plugin catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4AGi.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to an issue with the public file server. It should work now. Incidentally, the version is now 0.1.12. Please retry.